# gawk: printf output ignores OFS

Tags: awk, printf

When I use printf() in gawk the OFS separates output fields. However,in this script it ignores the OFS so output fields are separated by commas. Reading about the printf() function I don't see how to separate output fields with a pipe, "|".

```
BEGIN { FS="|", OFS="|" }
{ split ($6, a, "/"); printf "%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s-%s-%s,%s\n", $1"|"$2"|"$3"|"$4"|"$5"|" a[3], a[1], a[2]"|"$7; }
```

Thanks in advance,

Rich

Comment: The output separator variables OFS and ORS have no effect on printf statements. Read [printf](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Basic-Printf.html) in GNU awk manual. You can use something like that: `printf "%s|%s|%s\n", "arg1", "arg2", "arg3"`.

Comment: why the mix of `,` (with `OFS="|"`) and hardcoded `"|"`? with `OFS="|"` I'd think `print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, a[3], a[1], a[2], $7` would do the job ...

Comment: or `echo "1|2|3" | awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="|" } { printf("%s\n", $1 OFS $2 OFS $3) }'`

Comment: You actually HAVE commas in your `printf` format string. That is why they are there.

Comment: Got it, all. I'll modify the format string and replace commas with pipes. Thank all of you very much.

Answer (score 1):

The `f` in `printf` stands for "formatting" - you provide all the formatting as the first argument for `printf` instead of using the defaults like `OFS` as a separator or `OFMT` for numeric output as used by `print`.

When you write:

```
printf "%s,%s\n", x, y
```

you're specifically stating that you want a comma between 2 string fields. If you want to use `printf` but also want whatever value `OFS` has between the fields then you'd instead write:

```
printf "%s%s%s\n", x, OFS, y
```

which is equivalent to:

```
print x, y
```

In any case, I think what you're trying to do is:

```
BEGIN { FS=OFS="|" }
{ split ($6, a, "/"); $6=a[3] "-" a[1] "-" a[2]; print }
```

Comment: I want the entire line, not just the date field. I'll try print() and I'll modify the format string, too. Thanks.

Comment: My script prints the entire line. Did you try it?